# nginx Permission denied error

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm runnning nginx and unicorn to serve Rails application.
Unicorn and Rails app works fine, but nginx can't open rails public directory with permission error and return 502 Bad Gateway.

```
curl http://localhost/
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**var/log/nginx/error.log**

```
014/09/18 18:16:16 [crit] 16619#0: *1 stat() "/home/rails/public_html/rails_app/current/public//index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2014/09/18 18:16:16 [crit] 16619#0: *1 stat() "/home/rails/public_html/rails_app/current/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2014/09/18 18:16:16 [crit] 16619#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock:/", host: "localhost"
2014/09/18 18:16:16 [crit] 16619#0: *1 stat() "/home/rails/public_html/rails_app/current/public/500.html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock/", host: "localhost"
2014/09/18 18:16:16 [crit] 16619#0: *1 stat() "/home/rails/public_html/rails_app/current/public/500.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock/", host: "localhost"
2014/09/18 18:16:16 [crit] 16619#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock:/500.html", host: "localhost"
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user    nginx;
worker_processes        1;

error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024; # increase if you have lots of clients
        # accept_mutex off; # "on" if nginx worker_processes > 1
}

http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile                on;
        # tcp_nopush    on;
        # tcp_nodelay   off;

        upstream unicorn {
                server unix:/tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock fail_timeout=0;
        }

        server {
                listen 80 default deferred;
                # server_name example.com;
                root /home/rails/public_html/rails_app/current/public;

                try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
                location @unicorn {
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_pass http://unicorn;
                }

                error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
                client_max_body_size 4G;
                keepalive_timeout 10;
        }
}
```

The permissions for rails public directories are 775 or 775.
nginx is executed by 'nginx' user and rails public directories are owned by 'rails' user.
I've tried to execute nginx by 'rails' user and root user but the same errors occurred.
I have no idea what's wrong with this errors.
nginx works fine if I set root directory to /usr/share/nginx/html/.
My environment is Centos7 on Vagrant and rails 2.2.2 with unicorn gem 4.8.3.

[note]I know that /tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock need to be placed another directory by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272943/nginx-cannot-find-unix-socket-file-with-unicorn-no-such-file-or-directory), but I guess it's not the problem.

Comment: Are each of the directories in the /home/rails/public_html/rails_app/current/public path executable for the 'nginx' user? If the errno is 13, it must be a simple permissions problem.

Comment: Permissions are ALL 775 or 755 as above.
Additionally, when set root dir /usr/share/nginx/html/ works fine but /usr/share/nginx/my_html/ cause the same error though these are same permission(755) and belongs to same owner(root) and group(root).

Answer (score 3):

nginx runs as `nginx`user as your configuration states. You say your directories are owned by `root:root`.

Ensure that **each and every** directory from the root to the file attempting to be accessed by nginx has the right *execution* (and maybe *reading*?) permission. In your case, the *other* permission group (`chmod o+(r)x <recursive list of dirs>`).

If that is not enough, try to add the *reading* permission for *others* on socket files.

Normally now nginx will be able to `stat()` those files.

The fact that everything runs fine with nginx `root` being set to `/usr/share/nginx/html` is that those files have been created by the nginx package with an adequate mix of user/group/permissions...

Now, I see another (and bigger) problem: you try to work with nginx workers running as `nginx:nginx` and files owned by `root:root`, for which there is no *write* permission for nginx whatsoever. Any attempt by nginx to write on a socket will thus ultimately fail...

You should really rethink the whole construction of yours. Make nginx user/group and directories/files ones match in some way so nginx can open what it need to open (*execution* right on directories), read what it needs to read and write what it needs to write without relying on the *other* permission group which basically allows **any user** to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.
The problem is that nginx can't read /tmp/unicorn.rails_app.sock since PrivateTmp=true in `/etc/systemd//system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service`

These are what I dit.
**Created directory for unicorn socket**

```
mkdir /var/run/unicorn
chown rails:rails /var/run/unicorn
chmod 755 /var/run/unicorn
```

**Modified nginx.conf**

```
upstream unicorn {
    server unix:/var/run/unicorn/unicorn.rails_app.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

**Disabled SElinux**

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

**Disabled permanently**
/etc/sysconfig/selinux

```
SELINUX=permissive
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

And now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my nginx.conf and changed the user from nginx to deployer (my deployment user for capistrano and member of wheel group), and now everything works great!

Comment: OMG NO giving lots of privileges to your webserver is not a good way to fix anything.

Answer (score -1):

To check that the case is in SELinux, you can disable it

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

but it's not safe to turn it off, and the problem will return when you reboot

Good detailed article https://nts.strzibny.name/allowing-nginx-to-use-a-pumaunicorn-unix-socket-with-selinux/

In short, you need to execute the command and save the output to the nginx.te file

```
sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m nginx                                                                                                                        
                                                           
module nginx 1.0;                                          
                                                                
require {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        type httpd_t;                                           
        type initrc_t;                                                                                                                                                                                               
        class unix_stream_socket connectto;              
}                                                         
                                                       
#============= httpd_t ==============                        
allow httpd_t initrc_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

and then check, compile and subtract

```
sudo checkmodule -M -m -o nginx.mod nginx.te
sudo semodule_package -o nginx.pp -m nginx.mod
sudo semodule -i nginx.pp
```

Comment: selinux was invented for a reason. Disabling it altogether indeed can help to mask the problem, but suggesting it as a final solution is not a great idea. If it helps it is only the path towards the real solution which includes the proper configuration of selinux.